# Alignment of multiple (non-biological, discrete state) sequences

Tags: r, sequence-alignment

I have some data that describes an ordered set of discrete events (or states). There are 34 possible states, which may occur in any order and may repeat. Each sequence of events can contain any number of events, and crucially there are more than 2 sequences of events. My eventual aim is to cluster these sequences into similar subsets, but my hunch is that this cannot be meaningful unless these sequences are aligned such that equivalent events occupy the same position in all sequences.

I'm very familiar with multiple alignment of biological sequences, but all the software I've come across for this (MUSCLE, MAFFT, T-COFFEE, Clustal*, etc) require DNA, RNA or AA sequences, and I have more states than any of these, so I can't get them to work.

I've found various implementations of the *pairwise* alignment algorithms such as Needleman-Wunsch in R, but so far haven't come across any generic (non-biological) implementations of any *multiple* sequence alignment algorithms.

For example, say my data looks like this:

```
1: ABCDEFG
2: ACDGH
3: BDEFEGI
4: AH
5: DEGHI
```

My aim is to have it look like this:

```
1: ABCDEF-G--
2: A-CD---GH-
3: -B-DEFE--I
4: A-------H-
5: ---DE--GHI
```

Where the `-` symbol denotes the absence of an event in this sequence. This is a simplified example, in reality I'm looking for something that penalises the opening of gaps (`-`) in the same way that biological sequence MSA algorithms do.

The only piece of software I've found that seems to possibly do this is Alphamalig (http://alggen.lsi.upc.es/recerca/align/alphamalig/intro-alphamalig.html) but it's old and I can't get it working on my machine. Ideally I'd like something that can be implemented in R.

Comment: What logic is used in inserting a `-`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise using [MAFFT sequence alignment](https://mafft.cbrc.jp/alignment/software/anysymbol.html). Typically, this is used to align biological sequences, but it has the option to align text using --anysymbol. Note that MAFFT is a bash script and requires an input/output file.

input file (mafft_anysymbol_input.txt):

```
>Seq1
ABCDEFG
>Seq2
ACDGH
>Seq3
BDEFEGI
>Seq4
AH
>Seq5
DEGHI
```

R code to run bash script:

```
#Be sure that input/output and R files share the same path, otherwise you'll have to specify the path in the mafft script call.
x <- 'mafft --anysymbol mafft_anysymbol_input.txt > mafft_anysymbol_output.txt'
system(x)
```

Contents of output file (mafft_anysymbol_output.txt):

```
>Seq1
ABCDEFG--
>Seq2
-ACDGH---
>Seq3
--BDEFEGI
>Seq4
----AH---
>Seq5
---DEGHI-
```

Edit - I see now that you are familiar with biological alignment tools. If you want to make a customized scoring matrix for your text alignments, check out mafft options [--text and --textmatrix](https://mafft.cbrc.jp/alignment/software/textcomparison.html). It requires ascii code input (extra data type conversions), but you would have the option of associating similar letters (however you choose to define similar) by score. For example, you could associate upper and lowercase letters, or letters with/without accent marks.

Comment: Definitely a facepalm moment. Yes, I'm very familiar with biological alignment tools and I tried my data in several using their online webservers before posting this question. I gave up before I got to MAFFT ... even though this is generally my lab's preferred tool. Thank you so much for pointing me to this. I just wish I'd realised this four days ago!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we need to match with `LETTERS`, one option is `str_match`, then change the `NA` to `-`, `paste`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
f1 <- Vectorize(function(x) str_match(x, LETTERS))
out1 <- f1(v1)
do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(t(replace_na(out1[!!rowSums(!is.na(out1)),], '-'))))
#[1] "ABCDEFG--" "A-CD--GH-" "-B-DEFG-I" "A------H-" "---DE-GHI"
```

---

It can be also done with `match` after splitting

```
lst <- strsplit(v1, "")
mx <- match(max(sapply(lst, tail, 1)), LETTERS)
sapply(lst, function(x) paste(replace_na(x[match(LETTERS[seq_len(mx)], 
           x)], '-'), collapse=""))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("ABCDEFG", "ACDGH", "BDEFEGI", "AH", "DEGHI")
```

Comment: This is very clever, but my question was clearly not worded very well. The order of the states in each sequence is important, and your answer doesn't retain them, instead reordering them into alphabetical order. I can see how my lazy example made this misleading though.
Furthermore, the aim is not to insert all possible gaps to get a maximal alignment, but to reach some sort of optimal alignment in the same way that biological sequence aligners work. This would likely be a much more complex algorithm that perhaps simply doesn't exist in R.

Comment: @TJC Sorry, I was only looking at the example/expected output